# how to display multiple field values in a textbox according to criteria

Tags: ms-access, textbox

I have a form that has a hidden textbox which contains the primary key of a table. The table has the following fields: ID, firstname, othername, lastname, gender. I would like to display the names in a textbox according to the ID selected in the hidden textbox. I tried DLookup but that only works for one field and I would like to show the first, other and last names together with space seperator. Is there a solution?

Comment: if your form is bound on a table just change the source control to e.g. `=[firstname] & " " & [othername] & " " & [lastname]`. if none, create a stored query with those fields as one field and do the dlookup using the id. or do multiple dlookup which is not recommended, eg. `=DLookup('fname',srctble,criteria) & " " & DLookup('oname',srctble,criteria) & DLookup('lname',srctble,criteria)`

Comment: Form is not bound to that particular table so the query option sounds like the most viable solution. why is the multiple dlookup method ou mentioned not recommended? @winghei

Comment: it is not the optimal that's why

Comment: `DLookup` is not just for one field. You can easily do things like `DLookup("firstname & ' ' & lastname","tablename","ID=" & myID)`. Any valid MS Access SQL SELECT expression can be used.